# Hiding button inside table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Having problem hiding a button in a `UITableViewCell`. I am adding a button to my `UITableViewCell` based if the label.text is bigger than the label container, so if the text is truncated. I'm getting a problem or a bug, the button shows up even when the text is not truncated. This is how the simulator looks like.

[image]

So the button still shows when the text isn't truncated. I'm trying to use the console to figure out what is going on. It's weird because the console prints it out correctly, but when I start scrolling somehow it show's the label is truncated. Here is what the console prints out when the app first launches on the left, which is correct. When I start scrolling it prints out the one on the right, where Jackie should be false and not true.

[image]

Now I don't know why it is printing out true when it should be false. I'm not sure if this is happening because we reuse `UITableViewCell`. But this is how my `UITableViewCell` file looks like. Also the isTruncated is a helper method that I found that helps me check if the label is truncated or not.

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemDetailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var moreButton: UIButton!

weak var delegate: ItemCellDelegate?

var item: Item? {
    didSet {

        configureCell()
    }
}

private func configureCell() {

    guard let item = item else { return }

    itemDetailLabel.text = item.description
    itemImageView.image = item.image
    itemTitleLabel.text = item.name

    if itemDetailLabel.isTruncated {
        moreButton.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        moreButton.isHidden = true
    }

    print("Name: \(item.name)\nisTextTruncated: \(itemDetailLabel.isTruncated)\n")
}

@IBAction func showMoreBtn() {

    delegate?.getSelected(cell: self)
}
}
```

`UITableView cellForRowAt` Method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let item = categories[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]


    cell.item = item

    cell.delegate = self

    //Even tried updating the data model
    // categories[indexPath.Section].items[indexPath.row] = item

    return cell
}
```

Been stuck here for quite a bit trying to figure out what is going on, so I would really really appreciate the help.

Okay here is the `isTruncated` code. Here is also a link to a video I just posted up, for a better visual of the problem. [Video Sample](https://youtu.be/kgRBH9MitcI), pay attention to the Jackie cell/row.

```
extension UILabel {

var isTruncated: Bool {

    guard let labelText = text else {
        return false
    }

    let labelTextSize = (labelText as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
        context: nil).size

    return labelTextSize.height > bounds.size.height
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the reuse of cells, if that gives you an avenue to research.

Comment: To detect the problem with the reuse of cells, let set background of the cell to red color if not truncated.

Comment: @Scott.N okay so I add the background color to red in the prepareForResue Method. The background color is red for Jackie. Now what?

Comment: You set background color with condition `itemDetailLabel.isTruncated`?

Comment: @Scott.N no added prepareForReuse, just removed it and just added it in the itemDetailLabel.isTruncated. The Jackie cell is red

Comment: Now try testing show, hide morebutton at the place that you set the background?

Comment: @Scott.N I did but it still shows, that is the problem. Can't seem to figure this out. Okay just realized that when I scroll all the way to the bottom then back up the button is gone. Now when I scroll all the way to the top and back down to the cell the button is there.

Comment: Please provide the code how you get the `isTruncated ` value from the text?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed okay added the code and a video link

Comment: @Scott.N added a video for a better visual of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is getting the value of `isTruncated`. Try to use this extension for checking text is truncated or not. I think line number checking will be the trick to doing this.

```
extension UILabel {

    func countLabelLines() -> Int {
        // Call self.layoutIfNeeded() if your view is uses auto layout
        let myText = self.text! as NSString
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : self.font]

        let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / self.font.lineHeight))
    }

    func isTruncated() -> Bool {

        if (self.countLabelLines() > self.numberOfLines) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Faysal Ahmed thank you so much. This did the trick, was stuck here for a while. Now the only thing is that Xcode is giving me a warning.

Comment: Welcome happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for creating reusableCell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell
```

as?
 It will return an optional value and if the downcasting wasn't possible it will return nil and in your case because of guard statement it is returning UITableViewCell